Troubleshooting Sudden Drops in Home Network Speed
I'm having problems with my home network and looking to hopefully get some advice regarding this.
Setup:
1Gbps connection from my ISP via fiber. ONT is in bridge mode. After the ONT i have my main router (Archer A8) which handles the PPPoE. Also provides 2.4/5Ghz Wifi networks.
From this router I connect via Ethernet cable a second router (Archer C6) which is configured as access point in another room. The most special device connected (via Ethernet cable) to this second router is a mini pc which acts as my homelab server. It has proxmox with 4 guests fwiw.
I'm also exposing some services from this server through cloudflare.
Usually the speedtests i usually get are like this:

wifi: 350mbps
Wired Ethernet connection: 850+mbps

Problem:
A few days ago i noticed that my internet speed dropped to under 100mbs. Before calling the ISP I decided to restart all the networking devices just to exclude any problem with this. The restart fixed the problem at that point. But it happened again after 2 days.
Did not restart and did some investigation:

while connected to the main router (archer a8) i get proper speeds with no issues
while connected to the second router (access point archer c6) i get the lower speeds <100mbps

Without restarting any networking device i tried shutting down any of the connected devices (mainly the server with proxmox) but to no resolution.
I've also tried to restart only the access point but again did not fix the problem.
I will again restart the main router and will for sure fix the problem but only temporary.
Do you have any idea what could be the problem or what can i do to fix it?
In the mean time i've ordered a mini switch to replace my second router thinking it might be a problem with it.
Not sure how relevant these are but i keep seeing the same logs repeated in my main router:
307 INFO 1days, 15:58:32, [dhcp6s]unknow request opt code 31
308 INFO 1days, 15:58:32, [dhcp6s]unknow request opt code 56
309 INFO 1days, 15:58:32, [dhcp6s]unknow request opt code 83
310 INFO 1days, 15:58:32, [dhcp6s]unknow request opt code 103

LE:
Link rates reported by C6



Port
Status
Negotiation Speed




Internet
Connected
100Mbps full duplex


LAN1
Connected
1000Mbps full duplex


LAN2
Connected
1000Mbps full duplex


LAN3
Connected
10Mbps half duplex


LAN4
Disconnected
---



Manually setting "Internet Port Negotiation Speed Setting" in Archer A8 and a restart of C6 seems to keep the negotiated speed at 1000Mpbs/full duplex. For the moment...

What Ethernet link rate does each device report, for each of the involved ports? i.e. what rate does your computer show, what does the Archer C6 show for both ports, etc.

This is from C6. LAN1 is the server connected. I get the same reading on the server using ethtool....
Port Status Negotiation Speed
Internet Connected 100Mbps full duplex
LAN1 Connected 1000Mbps full duplex
LAN2 Connected 1000Mbps full duplex
LAN3 Connected 10Mbps half duplex
LAN4 Disconnected ---
seeing the internet -> 100Mbps i guess the speed tests is confirmed...
Question is why would it degrade over time

Hypothesis: a bad cable causes the link to be renegotiated down to 100 Mbit/s. Reboot resets negotiation and starts back at 1 Gbit/s.

@Zac67 will have it in mind. The thing is that all the cables are not easily reachable and have not been touched in a while.
Will trying to get the link rates i noticed i have manually set the "Internet Port Negotiation Speed Setting". I've selected 1000mpbs/full duplex (it was on auto). Restarted the C6 and not it seems it stays like that.
Is there anything i can do to test your theory? I'm not well versed in networking monitoring but i could give it a shot

You have already ruled out the main router and your ISP as the source of the problem. Leaves the secondary router or one of the links.
The next time you have that problem:

check the secondary router's log for any event that coincides with the speed drop
check the secondary router's indicated link speeds for its uplink (to the main router) and its downlink to the mini PC
check the mini PCs log for any coincident events and its indicated link speed

Very likely, one of the link degrades intermittently. Even though Ethernet doesn't train a link generally, a failing pair may trigger a renegotiation from four-pair 1000BASE-T down to two-pair 100BASE-TX (Broadcom's Ethernet@Wirespeed), explaining the speed drop. Once renegotiated down, the link will stay at 100 Mbit/s until you unplug and replug that link or reboot either end.
Once you've located the bad cable, you could run a temporary cable in parallel to see if it removes the problem. A major reason for a cable to fail is bad termination, so it might be worth the trouble trying to re-terminate the ends (perhaps one end fails straight away when wiggling it) if it's a problem replacing it.

Thanks for the detailed explanation. Will monitor the connection and act on the cable if needed
